# segmentation fault at av_frame_get_side_data

Tags: c, ffmpeg

When I executed the following code:

```
AVFrame tmp = frames_video1[k]; //AVFrame frames_video1[]
AVFrame *avf1 = &tmp;
AVFrameSideData* avfsd1=NULL;
if(avf1->side_data != NULL)
    printf("avf1->side_data is not NULL!!...........\n");
avfsd1 = av_frame_get_side_data(avf1, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
```

I came across segmentation fault happened at av_frame_get_side_data(avf1, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS):

```
avf1->side_data is not NULL!!...........
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

why?

Comment: It would be very helpful if we were provided with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, it appears that frames_video1[k] could result in NULL or some other invalid value, and you are not checking `tmp == NULL` or doing any other sort of sanity checking before assigning `avf1 = &tmp`. Even if it is not null, if you are accessing past the bounds of `frames_video`, you could be getting garbage data instead of null values.

Comment: frames_video1[k] is not null, otherwise there would not have been the output "avf1->side_data is not NULL!!..........."

Comment: either is tmp. How to do the sanity checking when assigning avf1 = &tmp?

Comment: You should first make sure you are within the correct bounds of `frames_video`. Then, before assigning `avf1 = &tmp`, you have to make sure `tmp` actually points towards a valid object, however that can be determined - having it not be `NULL` is one way. If you are still getting the error, use a debugger to determine the state of `tmp` when you are getting the segmentation fault. Still, without being able to reproduce the issue, these are only general suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

here is the output of gdb:

```
(gdb) print avf1->side_data->type 
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

(gdb) print frames_video1[1]->side_data->type 
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

surprisingly, avf1 points to a corrupted frame whose `side_data->type` is null, which is abnormal. The cause of the issue resides somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> AVFrame tmp = frames_video1[k]; //AVFrame frames_video1[]
> AVFrame *avf1 = &tmp;
> ```

You can't do this. I don't know where you learned this, but this is not allowed and fundamentally cannot work. You don't know the size of AVFrame in the application (it is not part of FFmpeg's ABI), so you cannot place a copy on the stack. Instead, do this:

```
AVFrame *avf1 = frames_video1[k];
```

Do not ever copy an FFmpeg object on the stack, it will not work. This also means frames_video1[] needs to be an array of `AVFrame *`, i.e. `AVFrame` pointers, not an array of `AVFrame`. If you don't understand why, read about pointers and memory in C and remember again that `AVFrame`'s size is not part of the FFmpeg ABI.

Now, let's debug your object. First, basics of C stack: how many frames are in `frames_video1[]`, and what is `k`? What is `frames_video1[k]->data[0]` or `frames_video[k]->linesize[0]`? Are they legal? Are you sure `frames_video1[k]` is a legal object? The fact that some copy of non-existing memory is non-`NULL` means nothing.

Secondly, if the object is legal, what is `AVFrame->nb_side_data`? You cannot access `AVFrame->side_data[]` beyond that index.

> ```
> (gdb) print avf1->side_data->type
> ```

You can't do that either. `side_data[]` is an array of pointers, so instead do this:

```
(gdb) print avf1->side_data[0]->type
```

All that said, I again highly recommend you to read up on C pointers and memory allocation, I don't think you entirely understand it. FFmpeg is a very low-level C library and not understanding C will cause lots of grief.